# Matrix representation of hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, time-evolution

I am studying spin-copuling and looking at an uncoupled harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian of the form:

$$H = \hbar \omega (a^{\dagger}a +1/2) + B \sigma_z.$$

I would like to write this up in a $2 \times 2$-matrix form, to investigate the time evolution of various operators, but the harmonic oscillator-term is seriously confusing me. How does one represent this in a matrix form?

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense until you identify that the various operators act on, i.e. until you identify the basis states of your Hilbert state.  Are they $\vert n, \pm\rangle:= \vert n\rangle\otimes \vert\pm\rangle$, in which case $a$, $a^\dagger$ act only on the oscillator part and $\sigma_z$ acts only on the spin part?

Comment: Well, that is part of the problem for me. I am trying to work out the density matrix $\rho (t)$, provided the spin state is $|\uparrow_x \rangle$ at $t=0$. I can write this as a superposition in the $|\uparrow \downarrow \rangle$-basis; so I have a Hilbert space with basis $| \cdot \rangle \otimes | \uparrow \downarrow \rangle$. If I choose $| n \rangle \otimes | \uparrow \downarrow \rangle$, then I don't see how it becomes a $2 \times 2$-matrix, since the first Hilbert space would be infinite-dimensional?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely, resolutely need to, then you can write your hamiltonian as a **formal** $2\times2$ matrix as
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix} \hbar\omega(\hat a^\dagger \hat a+1/2) + B & 0 \\ 0 & \hbar\omega(\hat a^\dagger \hat a+1/2) - B \end{pmatrix},
\tag 1
$$
but it is crucial to note that the entries in this matrix are still operators, and that this matrix acts on vertical arrays of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} |\psi_\uparrow\rangle \\ |\psi_\downarrow\rangle\end{pmatrix},
\tag 2
$$
where the $|\psi_s\rangle$ are states in the bosonic Hilbert space. If you want to have a regular matrix, because the bosonic Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional, you will need an infinite-dimensional matrix.

Frankly, from the way you've phrased your question, I would strongly advise you to leave the formal arrays of operators of $(1)$ and $(2)$ above for later, and keep to the (relatively) easier mechanics of tensor-product states evolving under tensor-product operators.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I understand where you're coming from, but if I were to write up the time evolution operator $U = \text{exp}(-i H t /\hbar)$, its hard for me to see how this would act on an operator, if I write it up using tensor products. For instance, if I have a density matrix, lets say: $\rho = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$ (written in the $| \pm \rangle$-basis), how would I go about calculating $\rho(t) =U^{\dagger} \rho U$?

Comment: @L.Henry No. I mean it. Leave the fancy schmancy matrices for another day and focus on the explicit Hilbert space mechanics until you've got them down pat, you do not sound anywhere near ready for the formalism you're attempting to crack. (Hint: you neglected to include in your density matrix any information about the field. Instead, each entry in your formal density matrix needs to be a trace-class operator on the bosonic Hilbert space.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty +1 for your comment.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see where the complexity arises exactly? The time evolution of any operator $A$ should be $e^{iHt/\hbar} A e^{-iHt/ \hbar}$. If I were to calculate $\rho (t)$ for instance, given $\rho = 1/2( |+ \rangle \langle + | - \rangle \langle - |)$, I get an infinite dimensional matrix from the first term in $e^{iHt/\hbar}$ (if I choose the basis $|n \rangle \otimes |\pm \rangle$ on the composite Hilbert space). I don't see any other way of doing this calculation exactly, unless you can clarify what you mean by letting the "product states evolve under tensor-product operators"? TY.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Perhaps I should be more clear:

I'm trying to calculate the time evolution of the density matrix $\rho (t)$, where $\rho ( 0 )$ is what I wrote before (in the $| \pm \rangle$-basis).

The "natural" step would ofcourse be to write $\rho (t) = U^{\dagger}(t) \rho (0) U (t)$. 

But I get lost here, because I don't understand the action from the $a_{+} a_{-}$-term. If I could get a regular matrix representation of this, I could simply work out the exponentials and take it from there, but (as you said) the bosonic Hilbert space is inf-dimensional.